# Script to add a Time Stamp

Tags: google-apps-script

Good day,

I have created a sheet that I use to track all changes that are made in Operations. I have a script that copies the range of cells and adds it to a registry on another tab. Where I am running into issues is adding the time stamp to the entries. I have used several variations of the following:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

I have not been able to get this to work in this way up to this point but I have been able to get it to work in the instance that I am manually inputting the information into a cell.

Is there a way to get this formula to function assuming that the edit is being done by another script and not manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Disregard this question. Since I am copying information into a registry log, I simply added a column with now() and copied that over with each submission. Don't know why I didn't think of that sooner.

Comment: Just so that you know.  onEdit triggers are only generated for user edits.